# Add padding-top in react-virtualized <List />

Tags: css, reactjs, react-virtualized

I have a `<List />` component where I want to add an initial `padding-top` to the *wrapper*. Since all the elements are `absolute` positioned I found this solution but I wonder if it's right or is there another solution less expensive:

```
const rowRenderer = ({ index, key, style, isScrolling }) => {
// ...

return (
  <ul key={key}
    style={{
      ...style,
      top: style.top + 50,
    }}>
    { items.map(itemRenderer) }
  </ul>
)
```

}

The related part is the `style` prop.

Comment: What do you mean by _less expensive_?  And why do all the elements have `absolute` positioning?

Comment: @Pineda `absolute` positioned elems is a core behaviour of `react-virtualized` when render items. Take a look here https://bvaughn.github.io/connect-tech-2016/#/8/5

Comment: with _less expensive_ I mean if there is an API method or something to avoid _spread_ the calculated `style` and re-calculate with my desired `50px` of `padding`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can avoid the unnecessary object-creation and spread operation by moving the padding to the level of the `List`, eg:

```
<List
  {...props}
  style={{
    paddingTop: '50px',
    boxSizing: 'content-box',
  }}
  containerStyle={{
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'visible'
  }}
/>
```

See an example of this here: https://plnkr.co/edit/vNHDmpEY2bjQbCup4xsG?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @brianvaughn for the reply (and for the awesome `react-virtualized` definitely) and sorry the delay. I tried this solution before but didn't work. I created [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fDKEChE2zhQS37W8IZg2?p=preview) to illustrate. See the `box-shadow` showed when each _item_ is hovered and how cuts the top side of the first row.

Comment: Take a look instead in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NmpBuCPSplv9UBTydJsm?p=preview) where I'm applying the solution exposed in the initial question. There's a subtle difference, looking the first _row_ when `:hover` an item

Comment: Maybe something more like this instead? https://plnkr.co/edit/vNHDmpEY2bjQbCup4xsG?p=preview

Comment: yup! thanks @brianvaughn, that's it! `containerStyle` ftw

Comment: I'm seeing again the [List docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md) and realising that there isn't this `prop` in the table, but it is in the `Grid` one. Looking into the `List` [source](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/List/List.js#L144-L156) I understand that inherits this (and other) props. Maybe could be useful a little advice/tip, could make a PR in case. Thanks again for the great stuff you are doing

Comment: I welcome PRs that improve the docs. If you have ideas- please feel free to submit one.

Comment: Edited my answer to include the more recent Plnkr approach.

Comment: Doesn't work - when the list is scrolled, elements on top of the list get clipped earlier than they should.